# Custom Git Credential Helper

Tags: git

I run `git` from a sandboxed environment. That means that `git` cant see `ssh-agent` or they system keychain to fetch credentials. Now I wanted to write a custom credential helper<sup>1</sup> using the credential api<sup>2</sup>, that I can bundle with my executable and use it's own credential keychain.

It seems though, that credentials helpers can only be configured statically for each URL using the `.gitconfig`.

Is there a way to tell `git push/pull/fetch` to use the custom helper by passing it on the commandline, or some other way to provide custom credentials?

---

<sup>1</sup> https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials 

<sup>2</sup> https://git-scm.com/docs/api-credentials

Comment: Does it help that you can set `git` config options both globally (`~/.gitconfig`) and per-repository (`./.git/config`)?

Comment: If I set the helper locally though, `git` when called from the commandline also would use that helper. I'd have to set the config, push/fetch/pull, and then clear the config again I guess?

Comment: If that's your workflow, my question was probably not a very useful suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a custom configuration argument when invoking `git` by using the `-c` option:

```
git -c credential.helper=foo push origin master
```

More importantly, you may not need a helper, since you can also configure the credential helper to read from the environment (in this case, the variables `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`):

```
git \
  -c credential.helper="!f(){ printf 'username=%s\npassword=%s\n' "$USERNAME" "$PASSWORD" };f" \
  push origin master
```

Of course, you may find the custom credential helper tidier or more performant than invoking the shell, and that's fine.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I could work around the helper when using HTTPS using your method or by prepending the `username:password` to the URL, I suppose. However, the actual issue is SSH keys with a passphrase. How would I provide a passphrase via configuration?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've accepted it since its still good advice and I can use the inline `-c` despite having gone another route. I manually patched the `git` source and made my own build to support my needs.

Comment: You can't provide an SSH passphrase via a credential helper (or, really, anything other than something like Expect).  If you need an automated system to use SSH keys, remove the passphrase.

Comment: Can't remove the passphrase, I don't have control over whose key it is. I also made a custom `ssh` build for that.

Answer (score 0):

> More importantly, you may not need a helper, since you can also configure the credential helper to read from the environment

Another approach is documented in [`gitcredentials` custom helpers](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#_custom_helpers)

But (with Git 2.27, Q2 2020) the samples in the credential documentation have been updated to make it clear that we depict what would appear in the `.git/config` file, by adding appropriate quotes as needed.

See [commit 177681a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/177681a07ea1c486b41db666b67c2fabd3c5a1d8), [commit dbe80f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dbe80f928c762db21bb19d6969a804d437978741) (01 May 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1260f81](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1260f819aa757c184b2d7afd6f27ad48f625677b), 08 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`gitcredentials(7)`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/177681a07ea1c486b41db666b67c2fabd3c5a1d8): make shell-snippet example more realistic
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> There's an example of using your own bit of shell to act as a credential helper, but it's not very realistic:
>
> - It's stupid to hand out your secret password to `_every`_ host.
>     In the real world you'd use the config-matcher to limit it to a particular host.
> - We never provided a username.
>     We can easily do that in another config option (you can do it in the helper, too, but this is much more readable).
> - We were sending the secret even for store/erase operations.
>     This is OK because Git would just ignore it, but a real system would probably be unlocking a password store, which you wouldn't want to do more than necessary.

So, instead of:

```
[credential]
    helper = "!f() { echo \"password=$(cat $HOME/.secret)\"; }; f"
```

you will see:

```
[credential "https://example.com"]
    username = your_user
    helper = "!f() { test \"$1\" = get && echo \"password=$(cat $HOME/.secret)\"; }; f"
```

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020) adds a doc update.

See [commit 4153274](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4153274052eea5cf57cbffb6acafb1ec8699820b) (05 May 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 37b48f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37b48f0efcf14793315a8aa1056bd1976419efb3), 08 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`docs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4153274052eea5cf57cbffb6acafb1ec8699820b): document `credential.helper` allowed values
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>   <sup>Acked-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> gitcredentials(7) already mentions several possible invocations that one can use as the value for `credential.helper`.
>
> However, many people are not aware that there are other options than a simple credential helper name, so let's place some explanatory text in the documentation for credential.helper as well.
>
> We still refer the user to gitcredential(7) for additional explanations and helpful examples.

The [`git credential` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4153274052eea5cf57cbffb6acafb1ec8699820b/Documentation/config/credential.txt#L1-L10) now includes:

> ### credential.helper:
>
> Specify an external helper to be called when a username or password credential is needed; the helper may consult external storage to avoid prompting the user for the credentials.
>
> This is normally the name of a credential helper with possible arguments, but may also be an absolute path with arguments or, if preceded by `!`, shell commands.

And:

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), there are minor in-code comments and documentation updates around credential API.

See [commit 1aed817](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1aed817f99bf259ea18ec49829b8d46b914e0230), [commit 4b8938b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b8938be4c4ef2d87642988f3486bc15c366b617) (06 May 2020), and [commit bb98765](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb987657690b447ae9162ef3a5841d26eb82d806), [commit 7f53583](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f53583834f991eadcc371932e117317cb3c65c5) (05 May 2020) by [Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón (`carenas`)](https://github.com/carenas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aa28171](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa28171c2752c0aa04c2e25f2f79bc01a7f045d5), 13 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1aed817f99bf259ea18ec49829b8d46b914e0230): document protocol updates
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
>
> **Document protocol changes after CVE-2020-11008**, including the removal of references to the override of attributes which is no longer recommended after CVE-2020-5260 and that might be removed in the future.
>
> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f53583834f991eadcc371932e117317cb3c65c5): update description for `credential_from_url_gently`
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Jeff King</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
>
> [c44088ecc4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c44088ecc4b0722636e0a305f9608d3047197282) ("`credential`: treat URL without scheme as invalid", 2020-04-18, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/048abe1751e6727bfbacf7b80466d78e04631f94) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e870325ee8575d5c3d7afe0ba2c9be072c692b65)) changes the implementation for this function to return -1 if protocol is missing.